# Reverse table in JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have problem reversing table columns. I've tried a few things but they didn't work at all. My knowledge of jQuery/javascript is poor but I need it for school purposes. The function should be made in JavaScript or jQuery

```html
<table>
  <tr id="header">   
    <th><a href="#">Rbr</a></th>   
    <th><a href="#">Ime</th>   
    <th><a href="#">Prezime</th>  
  </tr>
  <tr id="tabela">   
    <td>1.</td>   
    <td>Pera</td>   
    <td>Mikic</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr id="tabela">   
    <td>2.</td>   
    <td>Mika</td>   
    <td>Zikic</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr id="tabela">   
    <td>3.</td>
    <td>Zika</td>
    <td>Peric</td>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to reverse `1,2,3` to `3,2,1` by clicking on header `Rbr`. `Pera,Mika,Zika` to `Zika,Mika,Pera` by clicking on header `Ime`. `Mikic,Zikic,Peric` to `Peric,Zikic,Mikic` by clicking on header `Prezime`

Comment: Your question is too broad as it stands as you've shown no attempt to solve this yourself in the question. As a hint, what you need to search for is the `sort()` method in JS.

Comment: I did try sort() and reverse() but i have no idea how to connect it to specific collumn

Comment: In jQuery you can use `eq()` to get an element by its index: http://api.jquery.com/eq

Comment: Gonna try it out now @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: the duplicate I marked also has a solution for this exact problem. I would strongly suggest that if you're learning you use that code for a reference and inspect every line to understand exactly what it does and why.